# python split list based on condition/if else statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, split

I'm trying to split a list into two lists. Here's the list:

> L = [3.5, **1** ,7, **2** ,4.5, **1**, 6, **2**, 4.8, **2**
>   ,3.1,**1**, 9, **2**]

If I want to split the list based on the bold number (1 or 2), which are always the even number (2x) in the position, so the numbers before 1 go to one list, and the numbers before 2 go to another list:

```
l1 = [3.5, 4.5, 3.1] #bold number = 1

l2 = [7, 6, 4.8, 9] #bold number = 2
```

Also, the question may be extend when there are `i+1` bold number and thus needs to be split to `i+1` list.

How should I use `if`-`else` statements for list?

Comment: Please show your effort :) Pasting your code would be OK

Comment: Like 0Tech said, show what you have so far. But also clarify, are these numbers 1 and 2 positions or flags.

Comment: @Roxanne Your edit messed up the bold text in the `L` list.

Comment: @PM2Ring my bad. I will double check next-time

Comment: Thanks for your tips @PM2Ring! I thought I can only grant credit for people by clicking "up vote", which I didn't have authority for that. (I do now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do that using ternary in a step 2 loop which dispatches the previous element in the relevant list (I took a shortcut: if value is `1`, it's `l1` else it's `l2`, so it's rather fragile):

```
l=[3.5, 1 ,7, 2 ,4.5, 1, 6, 2, 4.8, 2 ,3.1,1, 9, 2]

l1,l2 = [],[]
for i in range(1,len(l),2):
    (l1 if l[i]==1 else l2).append(l[i-1])

print(l1,l2)
```

yields:

```
[3.5, 4.5, 3.1] [7, 6, 4.8, 9]
```

General case: create a list of lists according to the maximum index, and dispatch the value according to the index in a loop (`l[i]-1` is the 0-starting index and `l[i]` is the value to insert)

```
lists = [[] for _ in range(max(l[1::2]))]

for i in range(1,len(l),2):
    lists[l[i]-1].append(l[i-1])

print(lists)
```

result:

```
[[3.5, 4.5, 3.1], [7, 6, 4.8, 9]]
```

more "pythonic" for the last part using `itertools.islice` instead of playing with indexes:

```
import itertools
for i,v in zip(itertools.islice(l,1,len(l),2),itertools.islice(l,0,len(l),2)):
    lists[i-1].append(v)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a dictionary to hold the new lists, using the category number as the dictionary key. We use a defaultdict to simplify creating the lists in the dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [3.5, 1 ,7, 2, 4.5, 1, 6, 2, 4.8, 2, 3.1, 1, 9, 2]

# Separate data into different lists based on following number
d = defaultdict(list)
it = iter(lst)
for v, k in zip(it, it):
    d[k].append(v) 

# Display lists
for k in sorted(d.keys()):
    print(k, d[k])
```

**output**

```
1 [3.5, 4.5, 3.1]
2 [7, 6, 4.8, 9]
```

This code copes with any number of categories.

As Jean-François Fabre mentions in the comments there's a slightly more efficient way to do the printing in sorted order.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [3.5, 1 ,7, 2, 4.5, 3, 6, 2, 4.8, 3, 3.1, 1, 9, 2]

# Separate data into different lists based on following number
d = defaultdict(list)
it = iter(lst)
for v, k in zip(it, it):
    d[k].append(v) 

# Display lists
for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
    print(k, v)
```

**output**

```
1 [3.5, 3.1]
2 [7, 6, 9]
3 [4.5, 4.8]
```

The heart of this algorithm is

```
it = iter(lst)
for v, k in zip(it, it):
```

[`it = iter(lst)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) creates an iterator object from the list. We then pass two copies of that iterator to [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Looping over `zip` yields tuples containing the successive items from each of the arguments you feed it. In other words, if you do `zip(a, b, c)` you get the first elements of each of `a`, `b`, `c`, then you get their 2nd elements, etc.

But here we've passed `zip` two references to the `it` iterator. So when `zip` reads the next items from each of the two `it`s its really working its way through the pairs of items in `lst`. Thus on each loop of the `for` loop we get successive pairs of items from `lst`.

Comment: `for k in sorted(d.keys()):`: you'd better do `for k,v in sorted(d.items()):` so you don't need to do `d[k]` in your loop.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks. Why didn't I think of that? ;) And `for t in sorted(d.items()): print(*t)` is another option.

Answer (score 0):

not the cleanest attempt, but here you go

```
>>> L=[3.5, 1 ,7, 2 ,4.5, 1, 6, 2, 4.8, 2 ,3.1,1, 9, 2]
>>> o=zip(L, L[1:])[::2]
>>> o
[(3.5, 1), (7, 2), (4.5, 1), (6, 2), (4.8, 2), (3.1, 1), (9, 2)]
>>> map(lambda x: x[0], filter(lambda x: x[1]%2==0, o))
[7, 6, 4.8, 9]
>>> map(lambda x: x[0], filter(lambda x: x[1]%2!=0, o))
[3.5, 4.5, 3.1]
```